# Retrieving nest thermostat schedules

Tags: nest-api

I am trying to retrieve nest thermostat schedules. However i get back the object which doesn't contain the thermostat schedules in it.
Is there an api that nest has which i can use to retrieve the thermostat schedules

Comment: What have you tried exactly? What API calls do you make, what do you get back? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to get the schedules. I think it is for security reasons. 
But maybe it is possible.

For other persons it is better if you show some of the code and data. So we understand what you are doing. So like Holger Just said: "What kind of calls do you make, and what kind of data do you get back?"